# Remove a custom UIViewController class inside Navigation stack generically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, generics

I want to remove some controllers of specific type inside `UINavigationController` stack programmatically.

Working non-generic fuction:

```
    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        var controllers = [AnyObject]()
        for item in navigationController.viewControllers {
            if !(item is CustomViewController) {
                controllers.append(item)
            }
        }

        navigationController.viewControllers = controllers
    }
```

However, I'm trying to make this one becomes generic.

```
func removeController<T>(controller: T.Type, navigationController: UINavigationController?) {
    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        var controllerArray = [AnyObject]()
        for item in navigationController.viewControllers {
            if !(item is T.Type) {
                controllerArray.append(item)
            }
        }
        navigationController.viewControllers = controllerArray
    }

}
removeController(CustomViewController.self, navigationController)
```

After many attempts, it still doesn't work. 
 Can anybody help me please, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following code:

```
func removeController<T>(type: T.Type, navigationController: UINavigationController?) {

    if let navigationController = navigationController {
        var controllerArray = [UIViewController]()

        for item in navigationController.viewControllers as [UIViewController] {
            if !(item is T) {
                controllerArray.append(item)
            }
        }
        navigationController.viewControllers = controllerArray
    }
}

removeController(CustomViewController.self, navController)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It removes all `UIViewController` in `navigationController` stack